# How to add the custom event files to MoPub Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, mopub, millennial-media

I'm new to this and I really need your help!
I imported the MoPub SDK using Gradle on Android Studio, and I can't figure out how to add the custom event files (Millennial, AdColony) to the project. I tried to add the files to a new directory like the guide says [here](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-Third-Party-Ad-Networks), but I keep getting the same errors:

> Couldn't locate or instantiate custom event: com.mopub.mobileads.MillennialBanner.
>   MoPubErrorCode: Unable to find Native Network or Custom Event adapter.

I tried to create a folder called ***com.mopub*** (both under src and project directory) and inside another folder called ***mobileads*** and in there I pasted all the files. I tried different combinations but all failed.
Here's how I implement the SDK on the app's build.gradle:

```
compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:3.12.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
```

I'm not using ProGuard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.
Make sure you have all the files in a folder called **com.mopub.mobileads** and then simply drag and drop this folder under the ***java*** folder inside /src/main  of Android Studio's Project sidebar.